# Syntax highlighting in Notepad++ for C# exceptions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, notepad++

I work a lot with Visual Studio(C#), and I do this all the time:

1. Start debugging.
2. Get an exception
3. Press "Copy exception detail to the clipboard".
4. Paste it into Notepad++ to get a better overview.

Is there some theme that includes syntax highlighting for this kind of text?

Comment: You don't use the watch window local, the call-stack window, the thread window?

Comment: What do you want to be highlighted?

Comment: You can make your own plugin for it. Believe me it wont take too long. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. There is just C# syntax highlighting which will help with the call stack. There is no specific highlighting for exceptions (and in my opinion, the C# syntax highlighter is sufficient).